# .NET - How do I retrieve specific items out of a Dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net, dataset

I have the following code which connects to a database and stores the data into a dataset.

What I need to do now is get a single value from the data set (well actually its two the first row column 4 and 5)

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MTD_FIGURE_VIEW1", conn);

    da.Fill(ds)
```

So, I need to get two specific items and store them into ints, the psudo code would be

```
int var1 = ds.row1.column4
int var2 = ds.row1.column5
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Also, can some one shed a light on data tables too as this may be related to how I'm going about doing this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do like...

If you want to access using `ColumnName`

```
Int32 First = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["column4Name"].ToString());
Int32 Second = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["column5Name"].ToString());
```

OR, if you want to access using `Index`

```
Int32 First = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString());
Int32 Second = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString());
```

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar im a having a slight issue with 2nd variable, in the dataset the variable is a double i think so it shows up as (4.0000) how would i change that to an int#

Comment: In the code I have convert it into Int, you must see the value 4 instead 4.0000; Debug and check the variable value.

Comment: i get the following error {"Input string was not in a correct format."}

Comment: iv tried the updated version i still get an error {"Input string was not in a correct format."} , could it be that in the dataset the 5th column is shown as a double (4.000) and its trying to convert that into a string?

Comment: iv done the following  Double v1 = Double.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["WORKING_DAY"].ToString());
        Int32 WorkingDay = Convert.ToInt32(v1); any ideas on how i can get that all in one line of code ?

Comment: for those reading in the future, i feel you should cast once rather than ToString() and then converting to integer. but you'd have to be sure that what you're getting is what you're expecting.

Answer (score 4):

The DataSet object has a Tables array. If you know the table you want, it will have a Row array, each object of which has an ItemArray array. In your case the code would most likely be

```
int var1 = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString());
```

and so forth. This would give you the 4th item in the first row. You can also use Columns instead of ItemArray and specify the column name as a string instead of remembering it's index. That approach can be easier to keep up with if the table structure changes. So that would be

```
int var1 = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MyColumnName"].ToString());
```

Comment: he need 4th and 5th columns value instead 4th & 5th row.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use something like this:

```
int? var1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<int?>("ColumnName");
```

or

```
int? var1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<int?>(3);   //column index
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int var1 = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString());
int var2 = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString());
```

Comment: It will return 4th and 5th Row data. this code is not correct.

Comment: you are returning an entire row and attempting to parse it into an int.

Answer (score 0):

```
int intVar = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][n];   // n = column index
```