# Dynamically display the queried data into a row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page where people select the zipcode from the dropdown list. when a specific zipcode is selected, it takes to a page where the neighborhoods in that zipcode are displayed. I don't want to use a gridview rather the data should be displayed as one beside the other or separated by comas. I am using SQL database. Can anyone suggest me any ideas how I can achieve it?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = tc02e1p4; user id=zipcode_user; password=zipcode_!T; Initial Catalog = ZIPCodeRef");
    conn.Open();
    string query = " Select [Facility] from ZIPCodeReference where category = 'SNC' and ZIP='77003'";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    using(SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader() )
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {                        
            for(int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                for (int j=0; j < 1; j++)
                {
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();

                    var ColumnContentAsString = reader[i].ToString();
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.Width = new Unit("110%");
                    tb.Text = ColumnContentAsString;
                    cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                Response.Write(",");
                Table1.Rows.Add(row);
            }                        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try something that doesn't work?

Comment: I have used a table on .aspx page. in .cs code, I created the sql connection and got the data into the dataset. I am struck with sending each result of query into the table. I am trying around but couldn't even find anu information useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using ADO.NET, you can put the result of your query into a datatable, then use a foreach loop to loop through the result, each time adding to a stringbuilder. Then, have a textbox/ label to display that stringbuilder. Same procedure goes for Entity Framework.
  UPDATED: use this instead

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var myString = reader.GetString(0); //The 0 stands for "the 0'th column", so the first column of the result.
    tb.Text +=", "+myString;
}
```

Comment: I have used a dataset and entered the data into the dataset ds using adapter.Fill(ds); Now I am struck with how I need to send each result into the row of the table..

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346458/net-how-do-i-retrieve-specific-items-out-of-a-dataset

Comment: Hi, I tried it. I am getting the values but I am getting it in a row. How can I display the values in a single column?

Comment: This code displays the results row by row. I want the results to be displayed in a row with columns.

Comment: Now, I am getting it as one below the other. I want it to be displayed one beside the other or one result separated by coma with other.

Comment: I am getting the same result with "," at the starting of each textbox in a row

Comment: @Shavy so you want the results in single row with multiple columns as comma separated? right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the result in a single row with multiple columns as comma separated, this code works.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = tc02e1p4; user id=zipcode_user; password=zipcode_!T; Initial Catalog = ZIPCodeRef"))
            {
                conn.Open();

                string query = " Select [Facility] from ZIPCodeReference where category = 'SNC' and ZIP='77003'";

                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            TableRow row = new TableRow();

                            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                TableCell cell = new TableCell();

                                var tempString = reader[i].ToString();
                                var ColumnContentAsString = (i == (reader.FieldCount - 1)) ? tempString + "," : tempString;

                                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                                tb.Width = new Unit("110%");
                                tb.Text = ColumnContentAsString;
                                cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                                row.Cells.Add(cell);

                            }

                            Table1.Rows.Add(row);
                        }
                    }
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have changed the following things in your code,

- `Page.IsPostBack`
- Using statements for `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`
- Connection close

Also you should consider the [Parameterized query](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx) for your inline queries.